# Export does not include an index.html file

Tags: sxa

When exporting a site for agencies, the resulting zip file does not contain an index.html.

Versions:

Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 160729)
Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.0.0 for 8.2
Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.1 for Sitecore 8

Settings:
Device: Default
Exported Content: Whole Site
Mode: Agency drop

I also tried Author mode.  Same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did export report return any interesting information?
What you can find inside the package? (there should be **export-report.txt**, **styles-export** and **-** folder with assets)

Did you check Sitecore logs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The index.html actually exists in the zip, but is not visible under the standard Windows Expolorer unzipper for some reason. If you use 7Zip to unzip the the package, you should find all files there.

We've addressed the problem and it should be solved in the upcoming release.